# Searching through the GROUP_CONCAT values?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

If I have 5 names returned in my group concat, is it somehow possible to further limit the returned table? If I for example only wish to see the firms with the name of "Assembly", and if I use that in an AND

```
"AND cell_name = 'Assembly'"
```

Then my group concat will only show Assembly, not the rest of the 5 names, even though I would like that.

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cell_name ORDER BY cell_name ASC) as Cell,
integrator_country as Country,
integrator_name as Name

FROM sme_cells_integrator_link

INNER JOIN sme_cells ON
(sme_cells.id = sme_cells_integrator_link.fk_cells_id)

INNER JOIN sme_integrator ON
(sme_integrator.id = sme_cells_integrator_link.fk_integrator_id)

WHERE integrator_country = 'Denmark' 
GROUP BY integrator_name
```

What I would like is for it to return the type of order which have been selected, but still also show all the orders that firm has, just like GROUP_CONCAT normally does.

Without my AND, the returned data looks sort of like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+
| Assembly,Packaging                                  | Denmark | Firm 1       |
| Packaging,Palletizing                               | Denmark | Firm 2       |
| Handling                                            | Denmark | Firm 3       |
| Grinding / Finishing,Handling,Packaging,Palletizing | Denmark | Firm 4       |
+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+
```

WITH my AND, it looks like this:

```
+----------+-----------+--------+
| Assembly |  Denmark  | Firm 1 |
+----------+-----------+--------+
```

And what I would like is for it to look like this:

```
+--------------------+-----------+-------+
| Assembly,Packaging |  Denmark  | Firm 1|
+--------------------+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: I think you need to add some sample data, and desired output from that data. It's a little unclear as it stands

Comment: Your Group have only Rows with 'Fruit Order', because your filter... Thats not possible to get other Rows, without a subselect

Comment: I updated with a proper example, hope that makes it more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need your tables not the result, then we can make you a subselect.

But the other quick and dirty option is Having:

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cell_name ORDER BY cell_name ASC) as Cell,
integrator_country as Country,
integrator_name as Name

FROM sme_cells_integrator_link

INNER JOIN sme_cells ON
(sme_cells.id = sme_cells_integrator_link.fk_cells_id)

INNER JOIN sme_integrator ON
(sme_integrator.id = sme_cells_integrator_link.fk_integrator_id)

WHERE integrator_country = 'Denmark' 
GROUP BY integrator_name
HAVING Cell LIKE '%Assembly%'
```

As you can see, you would have a Problem with similar Names with this solution.

Comment: That is not dirty to me, that is exactly what i am looking for. I tried using having, but somehow i messed it up. Similar names is not a problem, it comes from a pre-selected list of names, which i control.

Thanks alot, accepted!